# Python: Count Unique Value over rolling past 3 days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a df that is a time series of user access data

```
UserID     Access Date
a          10/01/2019
b          10/01/2019
c          10/01/2019
a          10/02/2019
b          10/02/2019 
d          10/02/2019
e          10/03/2019
f          10/03/2019
a          10/03/2019
b          10/03/2019
a          10/04/2019
b          10/04/2019
c          10/05/2019
```

I have another df that lists out the dates and I want to aggregate the unique occurrence of UserIDs in the rolling past 3 days. The expected output would look like below:

```
Date         Past_3_days_unique_count
10/01/2019   NaN
10/02/2019   NaN
10/03/2019   6
10/04/2019   5
10/04/2019   5
```

How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straightforward - let me walk you through it via the following snippet and its comments.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate some dates
dates = pd.date_range("01-01-2016", "01-10-2016", freq="6H")

# Generate some user ids
ids = np.random.randint(1, 5, len(dates))

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ids, "date": dates})

# Collect unique IDs for each day
q = df.groupby(df["date"].dt.to_period("D"))["id"].nunique()

# Grab the rolling sum over 3 previous days which is what we wanted
q.rolling(3).sum()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tested it out. The rolling sum in the end does not take into consideration of the duplicated user IDs between days though. For example. If user ID "b" happens on the first and second day, they will be double counted.

Answer (score -1):

Use pandas groupby the documentation is very good